# Android share intent chooser - only mail and clipboard

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I would like to have a share action that will popup a chooser only with email options (email, gmail... according to installed apps) and also copy to clipboard.
any snippet would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
this is what I've tried so far:

```
    Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","", null));
    email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, entry.getDisplayName());
    email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");

    Intent clipboardIntent = new Intent();
    clipboardIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.docs", "com.google.android.apps.docs.app.SendTextToClipboardActivity"));
    clipboardIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    clipboardIntent.setType("text/plain");
    clipboardIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to copy to clipboard");

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(email_intent, "Share entry");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { clipboardIntent });
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

but it only shows me the email options.
Iv'e also tried to use my own CopyToClipboardActivity but still same result

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: @roeiki11  If the answer helps you, kindly mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email body");
//emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, body); //If you are using HTML in your body text

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Chooser Title"));
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I add the "copy to clipboard" option?

Comment: when start this intent your subject and body is already pasted in selected mail engine.

Comment: but I want it as an option (after all the email options)